# (Android) Lleno una lista con elementos de Firebase pero se muestra vacía

Tags: android, firebase

Estoy llenando una lista con unos elementos que tengo en firebase database al pulsar un botón, pero cuando muestro el tamaño de la lista, me sale vacía. Ya me he asegurado de que hay elementos en la base de datos. La duda está en el método addValueEventListener. Aquí está el código:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_proyecto);
        miEditTextAddProyNombre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAddProyNombre);
        miEditTextAddProyArea = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAddProyArea);
        miEditTextAddProyFecha = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAddProyFecha);
        miEditTextAddProyFoto = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAddProyFoto);
        miEditTextAddProyVideo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAddProyVideo);
        miEditTextAddProyDescripcion = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAddProyDescripcion);
        miBotonAddProy = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botonAddProy);
        miListaProfes = new ArrayList<>();

        Alumno alum = (Alumno) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("Alumno");
        miEditTextAddProyArea.setText(alum.getArea());

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Madrid"));
            mes = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            anio = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            miEditTextAddProyFecha.setText(nomMes(mes) + "/" + String.valueOf(anio));
        }

        miBotonAddProy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                profesordb.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        miListaProfes.clear();
                        for(DataSnapshot snap:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                            Profesor profe = snap.getValue(Profesor.class);
                            miListaProfes.add(profe);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });

        Log.i("Taggg", String.valueOf(miListaProfes.size()));
    }
```

Comment: Te has asegurado que la están bien las referencias Child a Firebase

Comment: Sí, me he asegurado de esos pequeños detalles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu lista parece vacía porque, cuando se invoca el método con el **Button** se conecta el oyente, es decir, el **addValueEventListener**. Al no haber ningún cambio en la base de datos de **firebase** se salta el **onDataChange**. Pero si hubo un cambio en la base de datos y no está conectado, de igual forma se salta y es hasta después cuando hace el **onDataChange**.

En otras palabras lo primero que hace es conectarse y después verifica si existe algún cambio. A partir de la primera conexión tu **Log** debería mostrar el tamaño de la lista cada vez que se presiona el botón.

Te sugiero que veas correr el log cuando colocas otra en el **onDataChange**

```
 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        miListaProfes.clear();
                        for(DataSnapshot snap:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                            Profesor profe = snap.getValue(Profesor.class);
                            Log.w(TAG, "Profesor: "+profe.getName()); //Ejemplo
                            miListaProfes.add(profe);
                        }
                    }
```

De esta forma te darás cuenta que en el Logcat lo primero que aparecerá será el tamaño de la lista, es hasta después cuando el log del profesor es mostrado.

Si tu objetivo es guardar ese tamaño en algún sitio, lo mejor que podrías hacer es colocar el log una vez termine el for

```
profesordb.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        miListaProfes.clear();
                        for(DataSnapshot snap:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                            Profesor profe = snap.getValue(Profesor.class);
                            miListaProfes.add(profe);
                        }

                    Log.i("Taggg", String.valueOf(miListaProfes.size()));    

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

Así capturarás el cambio cada vez que el método se ejecute, después de todo para eso está creado.

Como dato adicional, el **addValueEventListener** está diseñado para escuchar los cambios en *tiempo real*, es decir, cada vez que exista un cambio en Profesor este lo detectará automáticamente sin presionar el **Button**. Incluso estando dentro del **onClick** del **Button** lo detectará después de hacer la conexión. No afectará tu base de datos pero solo te lo digo para que lo tengas en cuenta.

Traté de explicarlo de la forma en que lo he visto y en base a la documentación de **Firebase**, nunca me había detenido a hacer algo como tu problema. Saludos.

Comment: ¿No hay forma alguna de acceder a la lista ya llena de datos de la base de datos fuera del listener?

Comment: Por ejemplo, poner el addEventValueListener fuera del evento del botón y que al pulsar el botón compruebe si la lista está llena.

Comment: Bastaría con hacer una comprobación if si la lista está llena o no en el evento onClick. Si la la DB tiene datos, onDataChange lo detectará y lo agregará a la lista desde antes de presionar el boton.